# Why while loop is displaying single row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to run while loop in a while loop, but only single row is displayed.

```
  <?php    
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, c.fullname, ro.shortname, c.id as courseid
from mdl_context cx 
Left join mdl_course c ON cx.instanceid = c.id
Left join mdl_role_assignments r  on  r.contextid = cx.id
Left join mdl_user u on u.id = r.userid
Left join mdl_role ro on ro.id = r.roleid
WHERE r.roleid IN (11)
AND cx.contextlevel =50 GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY u.id ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo "<table>"."<tr>"."<td width='100px;'><h4>Name</h4></td>"."<td width='50px;'>"."</td>"."<td width='230px;'><h4>Email</h4></td>"."<td width='100px;'><h4>Role</h4></td>"."<td width='100px;'>"."</td>"."<td><h4>Course</h4></td>"."</table>"."<br>";
    while($tmg = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<table>"."<tr>"."<td width='100px;'><a href='http://localhost/user/profile.php?id=".$tmg["id"]."'>".$tmg["firstname"]." ".$tmg["lastname"]."</a></td>"."<td width='50px;'>"."</td>"."<td width='230px;'>".$tmg["email"]."</td>"."<td width='100px;'>".$tmg["shortname"]."</td>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo    "<td width='100px;'>"."</td>"."<td>".$row["fullname"]."</td>"."</table>"."<br>";
    }
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
 ?>
```

Any guidance or help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What about executing another query `$sqlt`

Comment: No definition for this "$sqlt" or it just a typo :P

Comment: What about the another query?

Comment: you are not executing your second query. check that.

Comment: I've corrected the code. Now outer while loop is executing once! Why?

Comment: Why you were fetching same array twice

Comment: Because at 1st i want unique records and in second i want to display all the courses related to 1st array id.

Answer (score 1):

A typo need to execute another query `$sqlt` as

```
$sqlt = "SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, c.id, c.fullname FROM mdl_course AS c JOIN mdl_context AS ctx ON c.id = ctx.instanceid JOIN mdl_role_assignments AS ra ON ra.contextid = ctx.id JOIN mdl_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid WHERE u.id IN ($newarray)";
$result2 = $conn->query($sqlt);//forgot to execute
while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Comment: I've corrected the code, now outer while loop is executing once! Why?

Comment: Why you were fetching same array twice

Comment: Because at 1st i want unique records and in second i want to display all the courses related to 1st array id.